# smartphone required the last version of ARCore

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have an adroid AR app, which i did with Unity. And it perfect works on my smartphone(Motorola g9 plus, 10 version of android), but it doesn't works at samsung sm a525f and samsung A51. Android version 11 is installed on these smartphones. When app is started, it required the last version of ARCore, but I already have this version:

[image]

**UPD**: Screenshot say, that the last version of ARCore is already download on this smartphone

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the screenshot say? Sorry I can't read it.

Comment: Hello, frankhermes! Sorry, it is my mistake. screenshot say, that the last version of ARCore is already download on this smartphone

Comment: What could be the problem? Please, help

Comment: maybe something in android manifest? because i am using custom manifest... The most interesting - it is that it works on Motorola, but doesn't on Samsung...